# Example or counterexample to this question about compactness.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $A$ be compact and $f$ be a bounded Riemann integrable function defined over $A$. Define $B = \{ x : f \text{ is discontinuous at } x \}$ and $B_\epsilon = \{x : o(f,x) \geq \epsilon \}$ where $o(f,x)$ is the oscillation function of $f$ at $a$.

Question: It's clear that $B\subset A$, now does $B$ or $B_\epsilon$ need to be finite? My first attempt was Dirchlet's function defined on $[0,1]$, but it was pointed [out](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781733/oscillation-set-is-compact?noredirect=1#comment1621076_781733) that this set does not have measure zero, so it's not a good example.

Comment: You forgot to add the assumption that $f$ is Riemann integrable or, equivalently, $B$ has measure zero.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo, thank you. Added

Answer (score 1):

With $A=[0,1]$, the characteristic function $f$ of the Cantor set $C$ is an example. The complement of $C$ is open, and $f$ is constant there, that is, if $x\notin C$, there is a neighborhood about $x$ where $f$ is constant, so $f$ is continuous at $x$. On the other hand, if $x\in C$, then arbitrarily close to $x$ there are points $t$ where $f(t)=0$: Consider any sequence $x_n\to x$ of distinct points of $C$ converging to $x$, and note that between any two of these points there is a point on the complement of $C$.

In this example, $B$ has measure $0$ but is uncountable (being equal to $C$), and coincides with $B_\epsilon$ whenever $0<\epsilon\le 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x) = 0$ if $x \neq \frac{1}{n}$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $f(x) = x$ otherwise. Then $f$ is Riemann integrable, but $B$ is countably infinite.

Comment: Is it possible to produce an uncountably infinite set? countable infinite is still too close for finiteness for me. But this looks like what I might be seeking.

Comment: Actually if I just change $n \in \mathbb{N}$ to the irrationals, that would still work right?

Comment: I cannot think of one off the top of my head, but try making a function that is discontinuous only on the Cantor set, because the Cantor set is an uncountable set with measure 0.

Comment: I do not think so. If your set of discontinuities is the set of all irrational numbers between $0$ and $1$, then it will not have measure $0$

Comment: Ah darn, I keep forgetting that fact...

Comment: See Ayman's answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552137/can-there-exist-a-function-with-discontinuity-at-cantors-set-union-z